# Why do Master Balls "almost always" have a legendary Pokemon in them?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In one of the tooltips in game, it says that Master Balls almost always summon a legendary Pokemon into battle.

What does it mean "almost always"? I've tested it so far, and I've consistently gotten Arceus, Kyurem, Entei, and other Legendary Pokemon, and haven't seen anything out of the ordinary.  Is there a list of Pokemon for the Master Ball or something?

Comment: Apparently, a Master Ball can occasionally contain a Goldeen. I don't have a good source for that information, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first master ball I used produced a goldeen, which just flopped around and did nothing.  So, a master ball does not guarantee a legendary.

This is a rare occurrence, though maybe less rare than getting Mew. I spent half an hour in training hoping to get it to happen again so I could record it but it has not happened yet.  In fact, when playing a game of stock 99 for 4 fighters and only Master Balls, Goldeen appeared onces as did Mew.  Each of the other legendaries appeared at least 4 times.

Comment: Haha, I was about to say "I bet a goldeen comes out every once in a while."